# Is it possible to provide geo tagging for entire city?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geotagging

I'm using geo tagging meta tags

1. position - contains latitude and longitude
2. Placename - contains city,state,country
3. Region - contains the city name

Do this geo tagging applies only to the specified locations pointed using latitude and longitude?. How can i point the entire city say new york. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Google Places Autocomplete API to accomplish this. Here's an example

```js
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  var latitude = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
  var longitude = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();

  $("#lat").val(latitude).change();
  $("#lon").val(longitude).change();
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&dummy=.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="address">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lat" placeholder="latitude">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="lon" placeholder="longitude">
</form>
```